# Android XML : Avoid specific element to move when virtual keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml

is their a way to prevent a specific element from moving when the keyboard shows up if I setted windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize in my manifest, or it's impossible ?

In my case i want the fragment to resize but the bottom navigation to go under my keyboard :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_nav_bg"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```